# serialport not getting available port

Tags: rust, serial-port

I'm trying to get information about available serial ports in Rust to determine which one I'm interested in to send data using the [serialport](https://docs.rs/serialport/4.0.1/serialport/) crate.

By doing:

```
serialport::available_ports();
```

I should able to get a list of available port. When I run the program as root (to avoid `PermissionDenied` error) the only result I'm getting is

> SerialPortInfo { port_name: "/dev/ttyS0", port_type: "Unknown" }

I tried to remove all USB devices and ran the program but the result is the same. So I guess `/dev/ttyS0` is an USB Hub but it is weird because it does not show me my USB stick, the keyboard, my mouse or my webcam.

I tried to open every `/dev/ttyS{number}` but the only one opening is `/dev/ttyS0`.

Here's my `Cargo.toml` file:

```
libudev = "0.3.0"
libudev-sys = "0.1.4"
serialport = { version = "4.1.0", default-features = true }
serial = "0.4.0"
```

I'm on Arch Linux and the program needs to be run on Linux. I installed the `pkg-config` dependency on the system and have udev too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite being the "Universal *Serial* Bus", devices on the USB are not recognized as being connected via serial ports. Actually, electrically it is not even a bus.

Only devices providing legacy serial transport like RS232 or RS485 fall in this category, commonly known as "COM ports".

There are serial ports connected via USB, though. These "virtual serial COM devices" commonly have the USB device type CDC/ACM and will be reported as /dev/ttyACM{number}.

Final line: You cannot access USB devices via serial ports, with the exception of virtual serial COM devices.

Comment: "*Actually, electrically it is not even a bus.*" -- So you're claiming they're lying when they say that the "B" in "USB" stands for "Bus"?  Why can't a (serial) "bus" share control and data lines?  What is *your* definition of a bus?

Comment: @sawdust I don't claim that they lie. An _electrical_ bus has the ability to let more than just the sender and a single receiver connect to the same lines. You cannot do this with USB, its electrical lines connect peer to peer. -- _Logically_ you may look at USB as a kind of bus, because you have a device tree that can be accessed through a single standardized interface. -- Of course, a serial bus shares lines between all participants.